# Unable to add a NIDAQ dll reference to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference, dllimport, nidaqmx

I have a project which is simulating a graphical environment. What I need in this program is to integrate it with NIDAQ library. Currently I am getting LNK2019 of unresolved external symbol.

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DAQmxCreateTask referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl    sofa::component::behaviormodel::MyBehaviorModel::updatePosition(double)" (?updatePosition@MyBehaviorModel@behaviormodel@component@sofa@@UEAAXN@Z) C:\Sofa\applications\plugins\NIPlugin\MyBehaviorModel.obj   NIPlugin

I have included header file and lib file into my project but as my project is very big and includes lots of library and sub projects it seems that I have to add dynamic library of national instrument to the project as well. However I can not add any new reference to my new code in reference option of my project (there is no browse option abailable). I have also tried adding the path of the .dll file to the additional directory of the project and it doesn't seem to work. but when I add my .dll to additional dependency in Input-->Linker section of the project I get LNK1107 error.

> LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2D0    C:\git\sofa\v15.12\src\lib\win64\nicaiu.dll 1   NIPlugin    1

Do you have any idea how I can make VS read my .dll file?

Comment: What bitness (32-bit or 64-bit) is your application?

Comment: it is 64
Actually I found out the problem.It turned out that NI has two versions of lib for his application one 64 bit and another 32bit and I was attaching the 32bit version to my 64bit project.
thank you anyway for taking time and replying @Joe Friedrichsen